# Multi variable Diophantine equation

Tags: diophantine-equations

Consider this equation
$$z^3\sqrt{x^2+y^2-z^2}=w(x^2+y^2)$$
where $w$, $z$ are positive integers, $x$, $y$ are any integers.

Squaring both sides we get the following Diophantine equation
$$z^6(x^2+y^2-z^2)=w^2(x^2+y^2)^2$$
Some solutions in non-negative integers are

```
(0, 25, 15, 108)
(0, 25, 20, 192)
(2, 2, 2, 2)
(2, 11, 5, 10)
(2, 11, 10, 40)
(2, 14, 10, 50)
(4, 4, 4, 8)
(4, 22, 10, 40)
(4, 22, 20, 160)
(4, 28, 20, 200)
(5, 10, 5, 10)
(5, 10, 10, 40)
(6, 6, 6, 18)
(7, 24, 15, 108)
(7, 24, 20, 192)
(8, 8, 8, 32)
(10, 10, 10, 50)
(10, 20, 10, 40)
(10, 20, 20, 160)
```

$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2-z^2}=t \implies x^2+y^2=z^2+t^2$$
My approach was to find integers that can be represented as sum of two squares in more than one way. And then check if $w$ is integer. Is it possible to find a parametric solution for this equation? Or maybe an efficient method (other than brute force) to find its solutions? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$(x,y,z,w)=(u^4 - 6 u^2 v^2 + v^4, 4 u v (u^2 - v^2), 2 u v (u^2 + v^2), 8 u^3 v^3 (u^2 - v^2))$,

where natural $u>v$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. A bit of explanation please, if you have time.

Comment: I think you meant $(x,y,w,z)$. Does this give all the solutions?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, fixed. This is just one of many parametric solutions.

Answer (score 1):

$$z^6(x^2+y^2-z^2) = w^2(x^2+y^2)^2\tag{1}$$

We consider simultaneous equation

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x^2+y^2 = z^3 \\ 
x^2+y^2 = z^2+w^2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Hence we get $z^2(z-1) = w^2$.

Let $t^2 = z-1$ then $(z,w)=(t^2+1, (1+t^2)t)$.

From first equation, $x^2+y^2 = (t^2+1)^3$.

Hence we get $(x,y)=(3t^2-1, t(-3+t^2))$.

Finally, $(x,y,z,w)=(3t^2-1, t(-3+t^2), t^2+1, (1+t^2)t)$